# How do I set netflow collector on CIsco SG220 switch?

Tags: switch

This is the first cisco switch that I am dealing with at home. Older, more consumer friendly, switch had simple way to specify netflow collector. Where can I set it up on Cisco SG220?

Answer (score 0):

The unfortunate truth is that it looks like the SG220 series does not support Netflow.

As you can see from the [Data Sheet](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/small-business-220-series-smart-plus-switches/datasheet-c78-731284.html) Netflow is not an available feature on this switch. The SG and SB series are generally designed for Home or Small Office use, and Netflow is rarely seen in these scenarios. Netflow is a feature of IOS, which these switches don't run and it also requires a significant amount of TCAM, which would be costly on a switch this size.

For Netflow, you really need to look at 3750-X or above. 2960-X may support this, but it is primarily a Layer 2 switch, so don't get your hopes up. Most Routers should support at least Traditional Netflow, with the newer models supporting Flexible Netflow as well.